# Tagger outputting duplicate entries

Tags: devdemon-tagger, tagger

Trying to just output entries that share the same tag but it's outputting duplicate entries.

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="{news_channel}" url_title="{segment_2}"}
    {exp:tagger:related entry_id="{entry_id}"}

        {if tagger:no_entries}
            <div class="large-12 columns">
                <p>No related entries were found.</p>
            </div>
        {/if}

            <h2>{news-heading}</h2>
            {news-content}

    {/exp:tagger:related}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Any ideas how to stop this?

Answer (score 0):

Ok had to re-look at things and got the following working...

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="{news_channel}" url_title="{segment_2}" limit="3" dynamic="no" disable="{gv-disable-default}"}
{exp:tagger:related entry_id="{entry_id}" custom_fields="news-heading|news-content"}

    {if tagger:no_entries}
        <div class="large-12 columns">
            <p>No related entries were found.</p>
        </div>
    {/if}

        <h2>{tagger:news-heading}</h2>
        {tagger:news-content}


{/exp:tagger:related}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```